# Creating new Conda environment messes with old environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have 2 different projects with different dependencies. One requires Tensorflow1.15 and another needs 1.14. I first created an environment `env1` and pip installed Tf1.14, ran my code, all went well. Then I created a new environment `env2` and pip installed Tf1.15, during which I could see it was uninstalling Tf1.14, I assumed it knew what it was doing. However now when I run my code in `env1` it throws errors because tf1.14 is removed and `env1` also tries to use tf1.15!

What am I doing wrong? I thought we use Conda to create completely separate environments for specifically this kind of situation but I'm confused.

Comment: Your assumption is correct: this should not have happened, but from your description it's hard to debug this. Can you try to include a reproducible example of this behavior in your question?

Comment: @cel just creating a Conda environment and then installing Tensorflow1.14 with pip, followed by creating another Conda environment where we try to install Tensorflow1.15 will show that the old tensorflow1.14 gets uninstalled, which shouldn't happen. I later read the docs and saw that pip and Conda don't gel well, apparently not well at all.

Comment: Did you install pip into your new environment first?

Comment: @darthbith I don't think I did, I had installed pip on my machine before installing anaconda

Comment: Then you have to install pip into that environment to be able to install packages using pip into that environment. Conda does its best to separately install **everything** including Python and pip into each environment. So you have to use the environment-specific versions of that. The exception is conda itself, because conda itself is aware of the environments, while pip is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have used pip to install the packages. If you have Anaconda you should use conda to install them. `conda install numpy` will install the numpy module.

You need

`conda install your-module`

Comment: thanks, I only read in the docs later that pip and Conda shouldn't be mixed, although pip-installs after Conda-installs should be fine (but this uninstall behaviour is not documented). My code needs pip installed Tensorflow, using virtualenv seems like the better option.